# SQL Server: Combine multiple rows into one row

Tags: windows, t-sql, null, subquery, coalesce

I've looked at a few other similar questions, but none of them fits the particular situation I find myself in.

*I am a relative beginner at SQL.*

I am writing a query to create a report. **I have read-only access to this DB.** I am trying to combine three rows into one row. Any method that only requires read access will work.

That being said, the three rows I have, were obtained by a very long sub-query. Here is the outer shell:

```
SELECT Availability,
       Start_Date,
       End_Date
FROM (
  -- long subquery goes here (it is several UNION ALLs)
  ...
) AS dual
```

Here are the rows:

```
Availability | Start_Date | End_Date
-------------------------------------
99.983       | NULL       | NULL
NULL         | 1/10/2013  | NULL
NULL         | NULL       | 1/28/2013
```

What I am trying to do is combine the three rows into one row, like so:

```
Availability | Start_Date | End_Date
-------------------------------------
99.983       | 1/10/2013  | 1/28/2013
```

I am aware that I could use *COALESCE()* to put them in one column, but **I would prefer to keep the three separate columns**.

**I can't create or use stored procedures.**

Is it possible to do this? Can I have an example for the general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using an aggregate function:

```
SELECT max(Availability) Availability,
       max(Start_Date) Start_Date,
       max(End_Date) End_Date
FROM (
  -- long subquery goes here (it is several UNION ALLs)
  ...
) AS dual
```

If you have additional columns, then you would need to add a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Spot on. Thank you for the quick reply, and the simple answer. This makes a lot of sense.