# Merge three rows into one row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where columns name as

```
[ViewAllLogId] primary key
[orderNumber]
[OUTGATEDATE]
[ARRIVALDATE]
[COMPLETEDDATE]
....etc
```

where for each [orderNumber] it has 3 rows in which one column[e.g OUTGATEDATE] is filled, other columns [e.g ARRIVALDATE and COMPLETEDDATE] are empty.
I want to merge 3 rows into 1 rows where all 3 column has its own value correspondent to that [orderNumber]

Comment: You mean, that you have for each orderNumber 3 rows, each row for OUTGATEDATE, ARRIVALDATE and COMPLETEDDATE. And you want to combine them into one row? Do you want to update your table or just do a select?

Comment: I have read this link but i want all column where other column value may be diferent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572395/sql-server-combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Comment: @PmDuda Yes, I want to update my table

Comment: Try aggregate than and check if it is what you are after: `SELECT orderNumber,  max(OUTGATEDATE) OUTGATEDATE,
       max(ARRIVALDATE) ARRIVALDATE,
       max(COMPLETEDDATE) COMPLETEDDATE
  FROM [YourTable] GROUP BY orderNumber`

Comment: You want to delete the duplicate records that have same order number?

Comment: Put an example of data before and after...

Comment: @PmDuda yes I tried this and it gives correct result but i want update these columns . After that I can retrieve all columns from my table using group by.

Comment: Do you want to update all the columns? So you will have 3 rows for each? Or just remove old data and then replace it with new?

Comment: I want update only 3 columns . I want value in all 3 columns with unique orderNumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group by `OrderNo` and then aggregate the date column for `max` value of date column

```
SELECT
  OrderNo,
  max(Date1) Date1,
  max(Date2) Date2,
  max(Date3) Date3

FROM YourTable
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

Check the attached SQL fiddle.

http://rextester.com/YZWR72891

**UPDATE**\

As you don't want the `select` and need to update the record in the table itself.
Please check the below fiddle.

http://rextester.com/GQA77937

```
update f
    set f.Date1 = s.Date1,
    f.Date2 = s.Date2,
    f.Date3 = s.Date3
From TestOrder f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OrderNo, max(Date1) Date1, max(Date2) Date2, max(Date3) Date3
    FROM TestOrder group by OrderNo
  ) s ON f.OrderNo = s.OrderNo
WHERE f.Date1 IS NOT NULL   -- apply this where clause so it will update the
                            -- date for single record only, and other 2 will have date
                            -- as null and we can delete them easily

DELETE from TestOrder WHERE Date1 IS null   -- delete the rows for order that has Date1 as null,
                                            -- so it will remove other 2 rows for ORDER
```

Comment: I already read this but I don't want select statement . I want update my columns. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572395/sql-server-combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row

Comment: as you have 3 rows so if you want to update these row, also want to delete other 2 rows?? then it will be 2 step process, update and then delete other two row, let me know then I will update my answer

Comment: YES , If you don't want to delete other rows then it will be fine also. I can manage with 3 duplicate rows also.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, One more question why at the end we are checking f.Date1 IS NOT NULL

Comment: Because I just want to fill other 2 columns value only for first row, not for other 2 rows, so it will be easy to delete the other 2 rows if required. I have provided the  inline comment, check that..

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution .
       UPDATE  T1
        SET T1.[OUTGATE DATE] = T2.[OUTGATE DATE],
            T1.[ARRIVAL DATE] = T2.[ARRIVAL DATE],
            T1.[COMPLETED DATE] = T2.[COMPLETED DATE]
        FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN`enter code here`
        (
            SELECT  [PRO #],
                MAX([OUTGATE DATE]) AS [OUTGATE DATE],
                MAX([ARRIVAL DATE]) AS [ARRIVAL DATE],
                MAX([COMPLETED DATE]) AS [COMPLETED DATE]
            FROM #TEMP
            GROUP BY [PRO #]
        )
        AS T2 ON T1.[PRO #] = T2.[PRO #]